# javascript FizzBuzz / if else statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators, fizzbuzz

**Here is the code**:

```
var i = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

**and this is the output**:

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
16
17
Fizz
19
Buzz
```

The code is ok and works well but I don't understand why does it only print `FizzBuzz` when logical operator && is in `if` statement and not in `else if`?

Comment: Because once a condition is true, it doesn't fall through to the next condition. Use multiple ifs if you want that

Answer (score 4):

Once one of the conditions in the `if (...)` / `else if (...)` is `true` (from top to bottom), the rest of the conditions are not evaluated and the program goes into the next loop (next `i`) value.

If you swap the order:

```
var i = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 5 === 0) {
        // This evaluates to true for a number that is multiple of 5 and 3, and it prints "Buzz", and goes into the next loop.
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

If you are looking for a shorter version of FizzBuzz, here's an interesting answer by Paul Irish (added more brackets for clarity):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    var f = i % 3 == 0, b = i % 5 == 0;
    console.log(f ? (b ? "FizzBuzz" : "Fizz") : (b ? "Buzz" : i));
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/jaysonrowe/1592432#gistcomment-790724

Answer (score 0):

This is correct way with **else if** statement:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
 if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log('FizzBuzz');
  } else if(i % 3 == 0){
    console.log('Fizz'); 
  } else if (i % 5 == 0){
    console.log('Buzz');
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Another solution with **switch** statement:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
 switch (true) {
  case (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) :
    console.log('FizzBuzz');
    break;
  case (i % 3 == 0) :
    console.log('Fizz');
    break;
  case (i % 5 == 0) :
    console.log('Buzz');
    break;
  default:
    console.log(i);
    break;
  } 
}
```